# Remove trailing ".00" from numbers in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I'm trying to format numbers to have format "**0.##**" - so that integer be like integer (**12** be exactly **12**), decimals be like decimals with no trailing zeroes (**12.30** be **12.3** and **12.4321** be **12.43**), but in reality
for **12** I've got **12.** with this annoying decimal point and see NO WAY to get rid of it.

[image]

The same time if I choose Format -> Number -> Automatic, I've got calculated numbers be like **131.3666667** which is not my desired format.

In LibreOffice using format "**0.##**" removes unnecessary decimal point, but Google Sheets don't. If you know how to do it, please share your knowledge. Googling doesn't help much.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since I came across multiple blogs telling me that *"When you include the period in your format rule, the decimal point will always show, regardless of whether there are any values after the decimal."*, I think the closest you can get is to use `=ROUND(A1,2)` in a seperate column.

Comment: Thanks, @JvdV. These are bad news, but I will wait for possible solutions since I didn't found one.

Comment: Well, another option would be google-script I suppose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number format **0.##** works well with Google Apps Script. It does not leave **dot** to numbers that has no decimals.

The code below will apply number formatting to the whole Sheet.

Try this:

```
function formatColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns());
  range.setNumberFormat("0.##");
}
```

***Note:**

- You can change the range to column specific by changing the value of `getRange()`. Example: `sheet.getRange(A1:A)`.
- If you choose to format the whole sheet, you only need to run the script once to apply the format.

**Output:**

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Since we set the format to the whole sheet, It will automatically format any inputted numbers.

[image]

### Reference:

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Range.setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

Comment: Seems like a solution. Though it's awkward and unobvious (why it does work from script but not directly, Google?), it covers my needs.
Thank you very much!

Comment: So we cannot just use Number to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**hi i found the Solution :**

```
For Example let us say that you have the number 100 in the cell A1 ,

and you have the Number 99.9 in the cell B1 .
```

let us say you want to get the sum of them without having the.9 .

click on the cell that you want to add the sum on it :

**let us say it is the cell C1 click on it then add =INT //(MUST BE CAPITAL) :**

for example :

```
= INT(A1 + B1)
```

**then hit Enter .**

now the value of the sum is :

**199**

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to reach. No need to remove significant decimals, I need to remove only **trailing** decimal zeroes.

Comment: okay in each single sell for the integers numbers try to add :  `=INT(15) , =INT(20), =INT(65), =INT(2), =INT(2) , =INT(2) `

Comment: Thank you, the only issue here is that all these cells are calculated, so I cannot know beforehand which one will be integer and which will not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the result of these cells for further calculation (or if you do use, but don't mind losing some precision), you can surround your current formula with `Round(..., 2)` and leave the format as automatic.

Some examples of what original numbers will appear as:

```
1.004 -> 1
1.006 -> 1.01
1.096 -> 1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

my google sheet .atuomatically adds .00 after any number . .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFpVR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).